# Excel - base 27 three-digit Sequence enlisting

Tags: microsoft-excel

In a three-digit number increasing sequence, where the base of each number is 27, I am trying to make a list of all combinations, but without repetition of numbers. E.g 1,26,26 would not be an option.

The sequence would go like:

- 1,2,3
- 1,2,4
- ...
- 1,2,27
- 1,3,4
- 1,3,5

And so on.

I put the formula for column C (from C2):

```
=IF(C1=27,B2+1,C1+1)
```

And dragged it down.

I put the formula for B2: `=IF(C1=27,B1+1,B1)`, but it goes wrong.

Any suggestions, please? I prefer the formula, rather than VBA code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula is looking to see if the last number in that column was the end of a series.  If so, it starts a new series, but the new series starts at 1 more than the column to the left.  If it isn't a new series, it increments the previous value in the column by 1.

Columns A and B don't change until the column to the right starts a new series.  When it does change, column B follows the same rule of considering the column to the left if its own column is starting a new series.  So B2 would be:

```
=IFERROR(IF(C1=27,IF(B1=26,A2+1,B1+1),B1),"")
```

Once you get beyond the end of the entire series, columns B and C will display an error value unless you suppress it.  I wrapped the column B formula in an IFERROR test, which you can similarly apply to your column C formula.

Since you don't want duplication, only column C can go up to 27; column B needs to end at 26, and column A needs to end at 25.  The exercise is complete when column A is at 25 and the columns to the right reach the end of their series.  So A2 would be:

```
=IF(C1=27,IF(B1=26,IF(A1=25,"",A1+1),A1),A1)
```

Comment: Fantastic!! Thanks a lot. Wrapping up in IFERROR helped of course.